# WebClient encoding issue in MonoTouch when building for release

Tags: .net, ios, mono, xamarin.ios, webclient

I have been having issues with `WebClient` behaving differently in
release builds on real devices than in debug mode the iOS simulator.

Apparently the response from the server gets interpreted differently, and breaks in release builds:
[image: Screenshot from the DEBUG build running in the iOS Simulator]
[image: Screenshot from the RELEASE build running on an iPhone 4S]

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3826220/856403) seems to have an answer for a similar issue, but I don't want to hardcode the encoding in the app, even though it might not change in its lifetime, it seems wrong to do so as the information is already contained in the `HTTP response`.

I have already opened an issue with Xamarin to investigate this further.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two factors in play here. First:

> it seems wrong to do so as the information is already contained in the HTTP response

Yes, it does *look* wrong but Microsoft .NET's [WebClient.Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.encoding.aspx) is, by default, identical to [System.Text.Encoding.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.default.aspx).

MSDN quote:

> The default value of this property is the encoding returned by Default.

As such Mono (and MonoTouch) implementation of `WebClient` behave **identically**. This is often overlooked (works mot of the time) but it's a source of *hard to find* (not MonoTouch but .NET specific) bugs since there's **no warranty** about what the `Default` value can be.

MSDN quote:

> Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the default encoding can even change on a single computer.

The second factor is the iOS simulator is that: a **simulator** not an emulator. This has many benefits (e.g. it's much faster than Android emulators) but it also has it's drawbacks (few IMO but it only makes them harder to spot).

What this means is that the simulator does not try (much) to hide the underlying operating system (i.e. OSX) when using *general* purpose API, like getting the default code page. Since it returns a different value, `System.Text.Encoding.Default` will be initialized with a different code page, leading to a different implementation being used.

As such **setting your own encoding** to `WebClient.Encoding` is the correct (and safe) way to solve your issue (for any .NET application).

Answer (score 3):

I heard back from the Xamarin support team and they also suggested setting the `WebClient` encoding explicitly.

On my device the `WebClient.Encoding` was set to `System.Text.Encoding.ASCII` instead of `UTF8`, which is used in the `iOS Simulator`.

Still not a generic solution, but at least you can use the high-level `DownloadString`:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
    var response = client.DownloadString("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/58977881/umlautTest.txt");
}
```

Comment: Hi, I am a iOS developer, facing same encoding problem as you posted. Please see this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9891510/arabic-characters-issue . I dont know nothing about c#, .Net etc, but in server side we are using c#. I am sure that you have some tips to resolve this problem. Looking forward for your comment